# Regex: If/Else Condition in HTML Form Validation

Tags: php, regex, html, validation

I'm struggling with creating an If/Else statement in regex to a) validate a phone number format, then b) invalidate a certain set of phone numbers.

I currently have:

```
<input type="tel" name="mobilePhone" pattern="^(?:\+?61|0)4 ?(?:(?:[01] ?[0-9]|2 ?[0-57-9]|3 ?[1-9]|4 ?[7-9]|5 ?[018]) ?[0-9]|3 ?0 ?[0-5])(?: ?[0-9]){5}$">
```

as a way of targeting the following phone number formats (mobile numbers in Australia):

`0414570776`
`0414 570 776`

However we have a lot of `0411 111 111` or `0400000000` user entries that I would like to try and wash out before submission, but I can't seem to get it right.

I want to invalidate a series of numbers, but for this example, these two would suffice: `0411 111 111` or `0400000000`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: That's beyond the purpose of the `pattern=` attribute, but a [`(?!…)` negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) would technically do.

Comment: My gut feeling says do this _after_ submission. Doing this with one singular regex is a maintainer's nightmare, and on the server side you can simply keep a table of invalid numbers that you can check against.

Comment: You could check against a list of number on the client side too, in JavaScript, e.g. if you want to keep the server load to a minimum, but then it's easy for a potential hacker to look at the source and find a loophole.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/365wTE/1).

Comment: @mario Thanks mate this looks promising - but I'm not too familiar with regex. Looks as though I'll need to learn it now.

Comment: @MrLister Normally I would go this option too however we are running this test through VWO as an AB test. Technically what we are trying to do isn't the best UX, but we are on a mission to collect some data to help validate some thinking. So it's going to be hacky. Not really worried about hackers. It's on non-critical data and just within the AB test.

Comment: Can you specify the rules that constitute a valid phone number?

Comment: @ShammelLee
---
1. Must start with `04`
2. Must be a total of 10 numbers (including spaces)

However we want to invalidate

1. 0411 111 111
2. 0400 000 000
3. 0400 123 123

etc etc

Comment: @bnchndlr Thanks but I'm not clear on what you mean by "etc etc." Repeating numbers (`0411 111 111`, `0400 000 000`) is different than consecutive numbers (`0400 123 123 123`). I will satisfy condition 1 and 2 then we can proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

```js
var re = /^\s*\+?04(\d)(?!\1\s*\1{3}\s*\1{3})\d\s*\d{3}\s*\d{3}\s*$/;

console.log(re.test('0411111111') ? 'pass' : 'fail', '"0411111111"');
console.log(re.test('0411 111 111') ? 'pass' : 'fail', '"0411 111 111"');
console.log(re.test('0400 000 000') ? 'pass' : 'fail', '"0400 000 000"');
console.log(re.test('0412345678') ? 'pass' : 'fail', '"0412345678"');
console.log(re.test('0412 345 678') ? 'pass' : 'fail', '0412 345 678');
console.log(re.test('+0412345678') ? 'pass' : 'fail', '"+0412345678"');
console.log(re.test('+0412 345 678') ? 'pass' : 'fail', '"+0412 345 678"');
console.log(re.test('0412   345   678') ? 'pass' : 'fail', '"0412   345   678"');
console.log(re.test('+0412   345   678') ? 'pass' : 'fail', '"+0412   345   678"');
console.log(re.test('       +0412       345      678        ') ? 'pass' : 'fail', '"       +0412       345      678        "');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type='tel' name='mobilePhone' pattern='^\s*\+?04(\d)(?!\1\s*\1{3}\s*\1{3})\d\s*\d{3}\s*\d{3}\s*$' placeholder='enter phone number'>
      <input type='submit'>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Explanation

- `^\s*` - starting with zero or more whitespace characters
- `\+?` - followed by an optional `+`
- `04` - followed by a literal `04`
- `(\d)` - followed by a single digit (group 1)
- `(?!...)` - ***NOT FOLLOWED BY***

  - `\1` - the value of group 1
  - `\s*` - followed by zero or more whitespace characters
  - `\1{3}` - followed by `3` occurrences of the value of group 1
  - `\s*` - followed by zero or more whitespace characters
  - `\1{3}` - followed by `3` occurrences of the value of group 1
- `\d` - followed by a single digit
- `\s*` - followed by zero or more whitespace characters
- `\d{3}` - followed by `3` occurrences of the value of group 1
- `\s*` - followed by zero or more whitespace characters
- `\d{3}` - followed by `3` occurrences of the value of group 1
- `\s*$` - ending with zero or more whitespace characters

Comment: Thank you so much @Shammel-lee. Going to test this out today (been travelling) and respond to your previous comments. Thank you again.